# Angular Material mat-form-field Placeholder text on multiple lines

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-5

I use a regular `mat-form-field` with a `textarea` inside. My issue is that the placeholder text for this Textarea is rather long. In mobile, where space is more limited, this placeholder text is truncated by Angular Material with an ellipsis.

I would like to have the placeholder text adjust to space restrictions by shifting down onto the next line. So, for example, instead of:

```
This is a really long text and it cannot fit on a single li...
```

I would like:

```
This is a really long text and it cannot fit on a single
line
```

I have already tried various approaches to changing the CSS of the `mat-input-placeholder` and `mat-input-placeholder-wrapper`, with no success. I know that part of the solution involves changing the text-overflow property (below), but I can't get the other parts.

```
::ng-deep .mat-input-placeholder {
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`::ng-deep` is deprecated.

Instead, you should use `ViewEncapsulation` and control the CSS inside the component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

For placeholder (remove `placeholder` from element):

`<mat-placeholder style="white-space: normal;">{{question.label}}</mat-placeholder>`

Then add your CSS styles without `::ng-deep` in the `example.component.css`

```
.mat-form-field-label {
  white-space: normal;
}

textarea.mat-input-element {
  padding: 0px 0;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.mat-input-placeholder {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: While ng-deep is deprecated, there is no specified removal time: https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#index

Comment: Also, the suggested ViewEncapsulation.None technique is fraught with difficulties much more than ng-deep, because you will now leak your styling throughout your site.

Answer (score 1):

wrap text:

```
<textarea></textarea>

<textarea
  matInput
  #fileName="ngModel"
  name="fileName"
  [(ngModel)]="action!.params.file!.originalName"
  type="text"
  autocomplete="off"
  autocapitalize="off"
  readonly
  required
  [matTooltip]="action!.params.file!.originalName"
></textarea>
```

overflow-clip text:

```
<input/>

<input
  matInput
  #fileName="ngModel"
  name="fileName"
  [(ngModel)]="action!.params.file!.originalName"
  type="text"
  autocomplete="off"
  autocapitalize="off"
  readonly
  required
  [matTooltip]="action!.params.file!.originalName"
/>
```