# Angular material form field

Tags: angular, angular-material

How can I change the default behaviour of placeholder on angular material input.

I do not want ellipses and want the really long placeholder to be displayed in many lines based on input size.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kftq2z

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261524/angular-material-mat-form-field-placeholder-text-on-multiple-lines

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material mat-form-field Placeholder text on multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261524/angular-material-mat-form-field-placeholder-text-on-multiple-lines)

Comment: @Daniel I am getting you. But I have used input tag and this answer contains mat-placeholder.How can I do this with input.

Comment: I don't understand your question, update your stackblitz, or write the problem in more detail